# Android Build with Kotlin DSL - how to access flavor extra properties?

Tags: android, gradle, android-flavors, kotlin-dsl

Traditionally, in Groovy, it was possible to define flavor-specific variables in the `ext
{}` block, but switching to Kotlin DSL it seems that the `extra` map has the project scope.

It looks like it is possible to force a flavor scope for extras by using:

```
productFlavors {
        register("flavor1") {
            require(this is ExtensionAware)
            ...
        }

        register("flavor2") {
            require(this is ExtensionAware)
            ...
        }
}
```

(source: https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/issues/1254)

But if it needs to be used later, for example to tweak the variables based on `buildType` like this:

```
variants.forEach { variant ->
  val flavor = variant.productFlavors[0]
  val size = ?? // extra??
  variant.buildConfigField("String", "SIZE", size)
}
```

how would these flavor-scoped references to `extra` be used?

Answer (score 4):

Currently, only one working method to access ext properties on ProductFlavor is this way

```
    variant.productFlavors.forEach { flavor ->
        require(flavor is ReadOnlyProductFlavor)
        val properties = (flavor.getProperty("ext") as DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension).properties
    }
```

Or maybe more clear

```
    val flavor = variant.productFlavors[0] as ReadOnlyProductFlavor
    val extra = flavor.getProperty("ext") as DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension
    extra.get("myPropertyName")
```

It just does the same thing what Groovy does when you call the non-existing property `ext`

I created a feature request for making it easier
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161115878